# How to compile uint with single quotes?

Tags: eosio.cdt

When I compile my code I get this error:

`warning: missing terminating ' character
 const static uint32_t   default_max_block_cpu_usage                 = 200'000; /// max block cpu usage in microseconds
                                                                          ^
error: missing terminating ' character
 const static uint32_t   default_max_block_cpu_usage                 = 200'000; /// max block cpu usage in microseconds`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not directly related to EOS.IO, but you get the compile error because you are using a **single quote to divide your uint**.

**This character is reserved for declaring `chars`.** Here is a StackOverflow explanation to this: **[Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c)**

Just remove the `'` from your definitions and it will hopefully work.

```
const static uint32_t   default_max_block_cpu_usage = 200000;
```

Comment: this code is in `~/eosio/eos/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/config.hpp`,and it can be compile by eos,i don't know how to do.

Comment: What is the compile command you are using?

Comment: i just want in main.cpp add include `#include <eosio/chain/contract_types.hpp>`

Comment: `g++ -o main main.cpp -I~/eosio/eos/libraries/fc/include -I~/eosio/eos/libraries/chain/include -I~/eosio/eos/libraries/chainbase/include -I~/eosio/eos/libraries/wasm-jit/Include  -std=c++11
`

Comment: Do you want to compile a smart contract or the EOS.IO Software for running a chain?

Comment: just want compile a test program and this code include contract_types.hpp.thank you!

Comment: and i know `const static uint32_t   default_max_block_cpu_usage                 = 200'000;` can be compile success in config.hpp by eos.io's project.but don't know how!

Comment: Actually, modern C++ allows single quotes as digit separators, just for readability: `1'000'000'000` is more readable than `1000000000`. For example, [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) it says that, since C++14, *Optional single quotes(') may be inserted between the digits as a separator. They are ignored by the compiler.* So perhaps changing the compiler options from `-std=c++11` to `-std=c++14` will help.